# Assistance with ActionScript 3.0 statement

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'd like to write a statement that tests to see if a user has a key and has more than 20 experience points. If the user has both the key and the points test to see if the user's name is "Joe", "Harry", or "Susan".

ACTIONSCRIPT 3.0 ONLY PLEASE!

Thanks!

Comment: would you like fries with that?         This is not an ordering counter.  Please show what you've tried, and explain what the issue is.

Comment: Too vague. Experience points, user names, etc are not things that can be in an AS3 expression. Strings, booleans, arrays, functions, etc are.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear as you have not provided any sample code, and what type the user object is. I am assuming its a instance of the 'Object' class, here's what a sample code would look like:

```
private var user:Object;

if (user.key == 'valueforKey' && user.experiencePoints >=20)
{
    if (user.name == 'Joe' || user.name == 'Harry' || user.name == 'Susan')
    {
         // Your code here
    }
}
```

This is obviously assuming that the user object has these properties of key, name and experiencePoints.

Hope this helps.